# Laravel sorting 1st level collection by 2nd level value

Tags: sorting, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have users with (or without) posts and I want the order of users to be dictated by the last post (showing the users who have never posted, then posted the longest ago first).

User A has posted yesterday
User B posted a week ago.
User C has never posted.

The order of users should be C,B,A.

The following code is how far I've come, but I can't seem to get it right. The order of users is not as I would expect it to be. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
After removing the limit() on eager-load, The result of sorting is:
C,A,B, instead of C,B,A.

```
$users = User::with('roles', 'flags')->whereHas('subscription', function($x) use($category_id) {
    $x->where('subscription.category_id', '=', $category_id);
})->get()->load([
    'posts' => function($y) {
        return $y->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
    }
]);

$users = $users->sortBy(function($user) {
    if(count($user->posts) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return strtotime($user->posts[0]->created_at);
});

return $users;
```

Comment: Chris are the results of the first part of your code correct? What order are you seeing could you confirm your `created_at` are in the standard format of `Y-m-d`.

Comment: Hi Mark, my created field yields the following date format: 2016-01-13 08:28:57. I am seeing that some users who have posts, don't get pulled from DB with the any posts at all (only the last user in the array has value posts not empty. Even though I am sure the first user as sorted DOES have posts.

Comment: @ChrisHessler Your posts aren't being loaded because of the `limit()` on the eager loaded relationship. That `limit()` is not per user, it will limit the eager load to only one record total.

Comment: @patricus Thank you for that. You are right, however after fixing this, users that have posts, do return posts, but the order still isn't displayed as expected.

Comment: @patricus Actually, you've fixed it! Besides your point, I had my ordering wrong (ASC should be DESC). It works now. thanks! This seems performance sensitive though. Any way to limit the eager loading to 1 post per user? Only the last post?

Comment: Correct. You want each user's latest post to be first, so you order them descending. FYI, there is a `latest()` function that does this for you: `return $y->latest();`. You can pass a field name to it, but it uses 'created_at' by default.

Comment: @patricus You're my hero. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @patricus in the comment section, my final (working) code is:

```
$users = User::with('roles', 'flags')->whereHas('subscription', function($x) use($category_id) {
    $x->where('subscription.category_id', '=', $category_id);
})->get()->load([
    'posts' => function($y) {
        return $y->latest();
    }
]);

$users = $users->sortBy(function($user) {
    if(count($user->posts) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return strtotime($user->posts[0]->created_at);
});

return $users;
```